# Issue with printing json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some problems with `json_encode` with array which contains
Hebrew strings. When I just print it it's working and it's printing in Hebrew,  but when i do to the `json_encode($array);` is just print for me these chars:

```
{"0":"\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf\u00d7\u0090\u00d7\u0095\u00d7\u00a0\u00d7
```

The code I'm using is:

```
$College_Name=array();
$i=0;
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
$query="Select `College_Name` from  `IPQ_App`.`Colleges_Index`";
$res=mysql_query($query);
if(!$res)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
{
    $output[$i]=$row['College_Name'];
    echo $output[$i];
    $i++;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

**EDIT:**

ok i have some strange problem when i echo in the loop the collagname and after i am print the json encode the json encode print for me in hebrew but if i put comment on the echo command the json encode not working :
this following code:

```
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
  {

    $College_Name[$i][$i]=$row['College_Name'];
   echo $College_Name[$i][$i];
     $i++;
     }
    echo "<br>";

                 print((json_encode($College_Name,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|
             JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)));
```

and this is output:
הבינתחומי בהרצליה הקריה האקדמית קרית אונו מכון טכנולוגי חולון מכון לנדר מרכז אקדמי ירושלים מכון שכטר למדעי היהדות מכללת שערי משפט - המכללה ללימודי משפט שנקר - בית ספר גבוה להנדסה ולעיצוב
[["אוניברסיטת בן-גוריון בנגב \r\n"],{"1":"אוניברסיטת בר-אילן \r\n"},{"2":"אוניברסיטת חיפה \r\n"},{"3":"אוניברסיטת תל אביב \r\n"},{"4":"האוניברסיטה העברית בירושלים \r\n"},{"5":"האוניברסיטה הפתוחה \r\n"},{"6":"הטכניון - מכון טכנולוגי לישראל \r\n"},{"7":"מכון ויצמן למדע \r\n"},{"8":"אפקה - המכללה האקדמית להנדסה בתל-אביב \r\n"},{"9":"בית ספר גבוה לטכנולוגיה בירושלים \r\n"},{"10":"בצלאל - אקדמיה לעיצוב ואומנות ירושלים \r\n"},{"11":"האקדמיה למוסיקה ולמחול בירושלים \r\n"},{"12":"המכללה האקדמית אשקלון \r\n"},{"13":"המכללה האקדמית הדסה ירושלים \r\n"},{"14":"המכללה האקדמית יהודה ושומרון \r\n"},{"15":"ה

Answer (score 0):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) will automatically escape unicode by default. That behaviour can be avoided with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option:

```
print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Comment: i tried this it's same problem but now it's give me other characters : this is example :  "ï»¿××•× ×™×‘×¨×¡×™×˜×ª ×‘×Ÿ-×’×•×¨×™×•×Ÿ ×‘× ×’×‘ \r\n"],{"1":"××•× ×™×‘×¨×¡×™×˜×ª ×‘×¨-××™×œ×Ÿ \r\n"},{"2":"××•× ×™×‘×¨×¡×™×˜×ª ×—×™×¤×” \r\n"},{"3":"××•× ×™×‘×¨×¡×™×˜×ª ×ª×œ ××‘×™×‘ \r\n"},{"4":"×”××•× ×™×‘×¨×¡×™×˜×” ×”×¢×‘×¨×™×ª ×‘×™×